# Ocaml 99 problems: can't understand the solution for generating combinations

Tags: function, functional-programming, ocaml, combinations

https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html

I am trying to understand the solution for generating the combinations of K distinct objects chosen from the N elements of a list. Here are the code:

```
 let extract k list =
    let rec aux k acc emit = function
      | [] -> acc
      | h :: t ->
        if k = 1 then aux k (emit [h] acc) emit t else
          let new_emit x = emit (h :: x) in
          aux k (aux (k-1) acc new_emit t) emit t
    in
    let emit x acc = x :: acc in
    aux k [] emit list;;
```

The emit function is defined to accept two parameters:

```
let emit x acc = x :: acc
```

So I don't quite understand how the following line works since it call emit giving only a single argument:

```
let new_emit x = emit (h :: x)
```

Also, the new_emit function accept only a single parameter and is passed as an argument to the aux function, how can it deal with the following line (the emit here is called by giving two arguments):

```
if k = 1 then aux k (emit [h] acc) emit t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions in OCaml are usually curried, meaning that multiple argument functions are expressed by taking one argument and returning a function that takes the next argument (and so on). OCaml has some syntax sugar to make this nicer to read: `let f x y = ...` is short for `let f = fun x -> fun y -> ...`.

Usually programmers use such functions by passing all the arguments at once, but it is possible to only pass one and get back a 'partially applied' function as a result. That is what is happening with `emit`.

So you can read `let emit_new x = emit (h :: x)` as defining a version of `emit` with the first argument already supplied.

Answer (score 0):

The point that you are missing here is that due to currying and first-class functions, the number of parameters of a function is not as rigid as you think it is.

In this particular case, the definition of `emit` as

```
 let emit x acc = x :: acc
```

gives it the type `'a -> 'a list -> 'a list`. This type can have two different readings, you can either think of it as a function that takes two argument, one of type `'a` and one of type `'a list` and returns an object of type `'a list`. But, you can also read it as function that takes *one* argument of type `'a` and returns a function of type `'a list -> 'a list`.

The definition

```
let new_emit x = emit (h :: x)
```

is using this curried interpretation: since `emit` has for type 
`'a -> 'a list -> 'a list`, applying it to `h::x` yields a function of type 
`'a list -> 'a list`, consequently the function `new_emit` has for type 
`'a -> 'a list -> 'a list`. In other words, the function `new_emit` still accepts two input parameters, even if it definitions only involve one argument. Note, to make things easier to understand the definition of `new_emit` can also be written either

```
let new_emit x = fun acc -> emit (h :: x) acc
```

or

```
let new_emit x acc = emit (h :: x) acc
```

In context, the `emit element_list combination_list` is used to add a new combination to the list of combinations by taking the `element_list` and adding to it all previously picked elements. The definition of `new_emit` is then used to pick the new element `h`. In other words, this line

```
 if k = 1 then aux k (emit [h] acc) emit t else
```

means add the element list `[h]` plus all previously picked elements to the combination list since all elements have been picked, whereas

```
   let new_emit x = emit (h :: x) in
      aux k (aux (k-1) acc new_emit t) emit t
```

could be decomposed as:

First pick the element `h`:

```
   let new_emit x = emit (h :: x)
```

then construct all combinations where `h` is present:

```
   let combination_where_h_was_selected = aux (k-1) acc new_emit t
```

and then construct all combination where h is absent:

```
      aux k combination_where_h_was_selected emit t
```

p.s.:
As a far more advanced remarks on the subject of the numbers of parameters of a function, note that even "variadic" function are perfectly possibly in OCaml. For instance, an abstruse and inefficient way to define list would be

```
 let start f = f (fun x -> x)
 let elt x t k = k (fun l -> t (fun l -> x ::l) l)
 let stop f = f (fun x -> x) []
 let [] = start stop
 let l = start (elt 1) (elt 2) (elt 3) (elt 4) stop
 ;; assert ( l = [1;2;3;4] )
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the explanation of the code as well